# Trying to write a new password to file containing PHP with fwrite()

Tags: php

I have a `PHP` script that is executed when a user submits a **Change Password Form**. It runs great and I have had success writing to the file when using the `fgets()` and `fgetc()` methods (this required a lot of code). But I never wanted to do it this way. I want to be able to call the `$_SESSION["password"]` from my `pass.php` file and replace it with `$newpass` using the `fwrite()` method. The current code does not replace at all.

My `PHP` script.

```
<?php
$oldpass = $_SESSION["password"] ;
$newpass = $_POST["newpass"] ;
$session =  fopen( "pass.php" , "r+" ) or die( "Could not open file" )  ;

$session ;
$content = file_get_contents( $session ) ;
$content = str_replace( $oldpass , $newpass , $content ) ;
fwrite( $session , $content ) ;
fclose( $session ) ;
?>
```

My external `PHP` file `pass.php`.

```
<?php
session_start() ;
$_SESSION["username"] = "imauser" ;
$_SESSION["password"] = "imapass" ;
?>
```

Comment: Why does this scream DANGER?

Comment: @Fred -ii- There is no harmful data for anyone to use in the file. The file only contains the code mentioned. Plus I have an army of validation scripts to clean the form submitted.

Comment: I think there is something fundamental I'm missing about calling the file into a `string` or maybe there is a better way then using the `str_replace()` method.

Comment: Why are you assuming that's my downvote with an outright direct accusation? You think I'm the only guy that visited your question? Plus, why are you storing passwords in a session? I wouldn't worry much about business, I mean really. If you're going to base yourself on Stack for business-relation, I wouldn't count on it; even I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Because there was only one view at the time of your first post and the downvote was there. (I count my views in order to know.) Plus you haven't denied it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in `file_get_contents($session)`. 
`file_get_contents` expects a filename not a resource.

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: One problem though... I keep getting an extra `?>` at the end of the closed file. Could it be because my `PHP` is nested inside the `<form>`? Looked up and down for syntax errors and could not find any.